# MVC view not showing Temp Data value after controller is called

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am working on MVC application, 
On textbox Blur it's calling jQuery function which in turn call controller.

[image]

Below is the jQuery code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UserId').blur(function () {
        //alert(1);

        var userId = $("#UserId").val();

        var url = '@Url.Action("IsValidUser", "UserRoleCompany")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { userId: userId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The controller code is below,

```
   public ActionResult IsValidUser(string userID)
    {
        LMTUsage objLMT = new LMTUsage();
        LMTDAL objLMTDAL = new LMTDAL();

        try
        {
            objLMT.UserList = objLMTDAL.IsValidUser(userID);
            bool IsValidUser = objLMT.UserList.Any(cus => cus.UserId == userID);

            if(!IsValidUser)
                TempData["Msg"] = "Please enter valid User Id";

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserRoleCompany");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TempData["Msg"] = ex.Message;
            //return Json(objLMT);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The controller is working properly and get assigned with the value as shown

TempData["Msg"] = "Please enter valid User Id";

But view code is not showing the notification message when $('#UserId').blur(function () gets called.

```
@if (TempData["Msg"] != null)
{ 
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
 hidden="true">&times;</button>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
 <a href="#" class="alert-link">Alert Link</a>.
</div>
}
```

It should show,

[image]

Kindly Guide.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay in the **same** page! You cannot redirect using ajax so your `return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserRoleCompany");` is pointless. You should be using a `[Remote]` attribute for this so that a validation error is displayed in the same page if its not valid

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get that. But my query is different. If you can put some light on it then will be helpful

Comment: What do you mean _its different_? You are making an ajax call - ajax calls DO NOT redirect. You have not left the page and you are not doing anything to update the current page. [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should not work with temptdata in this case. Try to return the right Json (success or error):

```
public ActionResult IsValidUser(string userID)
{
    LMTUsage objLMT = new LMTUsage();
    LMTDAL objLMTDAL = new LMTDAL();

    try
    {
        objLMT.UserList = objLMTDAL.IsValidUser(userID);
        bool IsValidUser = objLMT.UserList.Any(cus => cus.UserId == userID);

        if (!IsValidUser) {
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Please enter valid User Id." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new { success = true, responseText= "UserRoleCompany/Index"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Something went wrong..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Then just check with your jQuery to alert with bootstrap JS or set the window.location to the url you get back (or whatever your idea is).